# Show phtml template in static block

Tags: magento-1.8, static-block

I am trying to show a inquiry form in a new static block, this is what I have done.

```
{{block type="core/template" template="app/design/frontend/default/default/template/imedia/productinquiry.phtml"}}
```

However it does not show anything. I am using Version `magento 1.8.1`

Comment: where did you put this code ?

Comment: In csm -> static block, I created a new static block name inquiry.

Comment: hey did you resolve your issue ?? if yes, feel free to answer your own question and accept it. Or accept below answer if it helped you to resolve your issue

Answer (score 1):

Blocks use the template fallback system.  You don't need the full path to your template file from root.  You just need it from the within the template folder. Also, don't forget to include a block name for reference.

Try this instead:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="imedia.product.inquiry" template="imedia/productinquiry.phtml"}}
```

Comment: But are you sure block directive works inside static blocks?? As far as I know it is not possible. Am I wrong ?

Comment: The template processor `Mage_Cms_Model_Template_Filter` renders these variables.  Check out `Mage_Cms_Block_Block::_toHtml()` to see how it works.